# Inject Schema JSON using Google Tag Manager

Tags: json, seo, google-tag-manager

We are trying to inject schema JSON for SEO using GTM, however, the page isn't able to detect the schemas while doing the rich result test or schema markup validator.
The schema is getting triggered the - when inspecting the network call. [schema json trigger using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n35C.png)

Is there something I am missing out on?

1. Is GTM the right way to trigger schema JSON on a webpage?
2. Will multiple triggers and GTM tags impact the page speed for the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is possible to inject structured JSON data using GTM. The main downside is, that it is only visible for JavaScript crawlers. In my experience, it is detected and processed by Google, but it works better implementing it backed-side directly into the .
2. Everything you do impacts page speed. The problem with GTM is, that it appends custom HTML tags to the end of the  and moves it up into the  afterwards, thus consuming some extra computation power.